# Using wide range inputs within one benchmark

Tags: java, jmh

I want to write a benchmark for a few map implementations, including one custom implementation. I want to test how it behaves on average over wide range of inputs.

As this is the first time I use JMH, using @Param looked like obvious choice. But it turns out that JMH won't use all of these different inputs in a single benchmark, but will run separate benchmark for each set of params.

Is there some feature that should be used for it that I'm missing or is just looping over the range of inputs I want in my benchmark the right thing to do here?

Update:

I implemented 2 different benchmarks, that give exactly opposite comparison results (note: This is special Map (doesn't implement Map interface) that uses 3d coordinates as key).

1. Looping over the range of inputs in benchmark

   ```
   @Benchmark
   public void benchmarkGet(Blackhole bh){
       //8*20 different starting positions
       for(int i = 0;i < 8 * 20;i++){

           for(int x = 0;x < 20;x++){
               for(int y = 0;y < 20;y++){
                   for(int z = 0;z < 20;z++){
                       Object value = map.get(x + offsets[i][0], y + offsets[i][1], z + offsets[i][2]));
                       bh.consume(value);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Getting only 1 value each time and using state to get different value each time:

   ```
   @Benchmark
   @OutputTimeUnit(value = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
   public void benchmarkGet(Blackhole bh) {
       Object value = map.get(x + offsets[i][0], y + offsets[i][1], z + offsets[i][2]));
       bh.consume(value);
       x++;
       if (x > 20) {
           y++;
           x = 0;
           if (y > 20) {
               z++;
               y = 0;
               if (z > 20) {
                   i++;
                   z = 0;
                   if (i >= 8*20) {
                       i = 0;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Which one is correct?

Comment: pls show some code

Comment: Note: this is also similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496949/benchmarking-java-hashmap-get-jmh-vs-looping but it doesn't answer my question: what is the correct way, which one should I trust?

Answer (score 1):

A JMH benchmarks attempts to very precisely measure the performance of a specific piece of code.

The question which implementation is faster can only be answered when that question includes for which inputs, because the answer can differ. To know which implementation is faster on average, you need to know the inputs you have to average over.

Because of that, saying either implementation is faster in general is impossible, and JMH doesn't attempt to answer that question.

You're running into problems asking JMH the question you're tying to ask, which one is faster "in general" because JMH thinks that's the wrong question, and makes it hard to ask it the wrong question.

The right implementation is in fact to use the `Param` with different values, get different benchmarks, and the result of your benchmark is the range of answers you get from that.

Your result after studying the results of the benchmarks may look something like that the first algorithm is x much faster for small inputs in some range, but x much slower for large inputs in some range. What conclusion you draw from that, which one is faster for your use case will have to be drawn use case by use case.

Comment: I knew what input to test with, but I didn't really know what is the right way of giving such huge amount of inputs. In this case, I knew that in any real-world case the inputs are going to be 3 integers that are close to some point in 3d space. And that's exactly what I wanted to test. So I'm not testing for speed in general, but in my specific case. But JMH has no standard way to do it, and the 2 ways I come up with give contradicting results. And testing on a few inputs using Param takes a long time and is inaccurate (too few data points). And even now I don't know which map is better.

Comment: @Barteks2x The problem with testing a range of inputs is that you may well be measuring the performance of the iteration. If that matters, the iteration itself may matter, and iterating is part of your benchmark. That can also explain why one way to measure produces different results than the other; you're measuring the iteration along with the .get operation. Take a look at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/ecd9e76155fe/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_05_StateFixtures.java to set up state.

Comment: So that's my question: How can I measure just the get() operation? If I measure many of them in a single "operation" I gat different results than if I measure only one get() per operation and change state for the next one.

I guess the only way to make sure which one is better is to actually test them in the real thing... but in the real thing I can't see what would be the performance of similar map in 2d, I can only see that in JMH (and the 2d version is what I need to match in merformance)

Comment: To measure just the get() operation, you measure a single invocation `return map.get(x + offsets[i][0], y + offsets[i][1], z + offsets[i][2]));` for some values `x`, `y`, `z` and `i`

I think I still don't understand what you want to measure. On the one hand you're saying you want to measure just the get operation over some well-defined input, on the other you're saying you want to measure a huge range of inputs (which will give you a huge range of results, which you don't seem to want)

Comment: I want to measure average get() performance with well-defined range of inputs (but range of inputs big enough that I can't just use @Param). And I found 2 ways to do it that give different results each (ie. what was the worst one in one version, becomes close to the best one with the other version).